# Set object attribute to its index in an ArrayList

Tags: java, object, indexing, arraylist, attributes

I am writing an java application. I have map of football teams where the name of the league is the key and an array list of the teams in the league is the value. I was wondering whether there is a way to set the 'leaguePosition' attribute of each team based on its index in the array list as I have the teams sorted by their points.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you don't just want to use a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how all your code is organized but *schematically* you could do it for all leagues in the map like this:

```
for(Entry<String, ArrayList<Team>> league : leagueMap.entrySet()) {
    ArrayList<Team> teams = league.getValue();
    for(int i = 1; i <= teams.size(); i++) {
        teams.get(i-1).setRank(i);
    }
}
```

<sub>`i-1` because the first index is `0`.</sub>